# Determinant of a matrix $P$ such that $AP=BP$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A,B$ be the two $3 \times 3$ matrices
>
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 3 & 4 &0\\0 &-1&0\\4 &4 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> $$B=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> -1 & 1 &0\\0 &-1&0\\0 &0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> Suppose that there is matrix $P$ that $AP=BP$. Prove that $|P|=0$.

---

My solution is very simple and I'm not sure if its currect.

$$|A|=-3 , |B|=3$$
$$ -3|P|=3|P|$$
$$ |P|=0$$

Other sultions are much longer. Is there a reason my prove is not correct?

Comment: I haven't confirmed the determinants of $A$ and $B$, but if they are $3$ and $-3$, then you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your proof would be correct$^{[1]}$ if your determinants were right ! But for me, $\det A =3 = \det B$. See [(A)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B3,4,0%5D;%5B0,-1,0%5D;%5B4,4,-1%5D%5D) and [(B)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B-1,1,0%5D;%5B0,-1,0%5D;%5B0,0,3%5D%5D).

You can actually see that if $\det P \neq 0$, then $P$ would be invertible, which would yield $APP^{-1}=A=B=BPP^{-1}$, a contradiction.

---

$^{[1]}$ provided that your matrices have real coefficients, and not in $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$.

Comment: My bad, Thanks alot!